# Java Having trouble printing my last year from the data outside of my loop

Tags: java, loops

I am trying to print how many days below 32 degrees on my file and how many days above 80 and the average of the max temperatures using my methods and a file. I read all the data from a file and print other stuff my professor wanted before but when I changed it to print the days below and above it would not print out the last year of temperature data right.

Here is the code for the first loop of the other stuff the professor wanted that worked:

```
    int currentYear= 1942;
    int prevOccurrence=0;
    for (i=0;i<=73;i++){
        occurrence = occurrence(year, currentYear);
        System.out.println(currentYear-1 +" [" + prevOccurrence + ", " + occurrence +")");
        prevOccurrence+= occurrence-prevOccurrence;
        currentYear++;
    }
    System.out.println(currentYear-1 +" [" + prevOccurrence + ", " + (year.length)+")");
```

and here is the output:

```
1941 [0, 365)
1942 [365, 730)
1943 [730, 1095)
1944 [1095, 1461)
1945 [1461, 1826)
1946 [1826, 2191)
...
2009 [24837, 25202)
2010 [25202, 25567)
2011 [25567, 25932)
2012 [25932, 26298)
2013 [26298, 26663)
2014 [26663, 27028)
2015 [27028, 27393)
```

see it goes from 1941 to 2015 and 2015 has data

in this loop, however, trying to find the number of days below or above values it does not give any data for 2015

```
currentYear= 1942;
    prevOccurrence=0;
    count =0;
    int lt32=0;
    int gravg=0;
    int gre80=0;
    average = average(tmax);
    for (i=0;i<=73;i++){
        occurrence = occurrence(year, currentYear);
        lt32 = (occurrence - prevOccurrence) - count(tmin,  prevOccurrence,  occurrence, 32.0);
        gravg= count(tmax,  prevOccurrence,  occurrence, average);
        gre80= count(tmax,  prevOccurrence,  occurrence, 79.0);
        System.out.println(currentYear-1 +" " + lt32 + " " + gravg +" " + gre80);
        prevOccurrence+= occurrence-prevOccurrence;
        currentYear++;

    }
    prevOccurrence+= year.length-prevOccurrence;
    lt32 = (year.length - prevOccurrence) - count(tmin,  prevOccurrence,  year.length, 32.0);
    gravg= count(tmax,  prevOccurrence,  occurrence, average);
    gre80= count(tmax,  prevOccurrence,  year.length, 79.0);
    System.out.println(currentYear-1 +" " + lt32 + " " + gravg +" " + gre80 );
```

output

```
1941 160 191 51
1942 164 191 35
1943 171 180 38
1944 180 182 52
1945 150 183 38
1946 157 198 36
...
2009 139 190 28
2010 129 202 60
2011 134 193 45
2012 139 196 46
2013 151 192 38
2014 139 189 39
2015 0 0 0
```

and here are the methods i used for it

```
public static double average(int[] a) {
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        total += a[i];
    double average = (double)total/ (double) a.length;
    return average;
}

public static int arrayMax(int[] a) {
    int max = a[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        if (a[i] > max)
            max = a[i];
    return max; 
} 

public static int arrayMin(int[] a) {
    int min = a[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        if (a[i] < min)
            min = a[i];
    return min; 
}  

public static int occurrence(int[] a, int value) {
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        if (a[i] == value){
            index = i;
            value = index;
        }
    if (value!=index){
        index=-1;
    }
    return index; 
}

public static int count(int[] a, int startIndex, int endIndex, double value) {
    int count=0;
    for (int i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++)
        if (a[i] > value)
            count++;
    return count; 
}
```

Comment: If 2015 is the problem, then show a [mcve] of just running the code against 2015.

Comment: Other suggestions would include trying to use the debugger functionality of the IDE of your choice

Comment: what is `year` in your program ?

Comment: I don't get `occurence`. Why are you setting `value` with the `index` value ? It seems that you used it to get the last occurence (not the first) so you will only find the first one because you change the `value` value. Just init `index` to `-1` and simply loop on the array (no other check needed). PS : in min and max, you could start your loop to `i = 1` since the value of `a[0]` is already in the variable ;)